# Git push origin master fatal error: Permission to railstutorial/first_app.git denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, railstutorial.org

I'm trying to git push origin master using Michael Hartl's rails tutorials (first_app), but i'm getting this problem:

```
[first_app]$git push origin master
ERROR: Permission to railstutorial/first_app.git denied to tomkim
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've re-entered an SSH key, but that's not it.  I've never had this problem before, but now I am.

Help's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to `ssh -v` to the server?

Comment: Are you attempting to push to the Rails Tutorial github account and not your own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add your own repo as the remote (of course you need to create a `first_app` repo on Github first):

```
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:tomkim/first_app.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

And `tomkim` is your github account name, right? If not, change it to yours.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.  I noticed that the origin was showing "`railstutorial/first_app.git`", when that it should've been `tomkim310/first_app.git`.  The problem to begin with was follow Hartl's tutorial, I was just typing as he was going.  Simply doing a new "`git remote add origin git@github.com:tomkim310/first_app.git`" does not do the trick.

I verified this by typing in: `git remote -v` which gave `origin    git@github.com:railstutorial/first_app.git`.  To change it, i typed: `git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:tomkim310/first_app.git`.

This then did the trick and `git push origin master` worked.